Adding together ai as a custom provider in a next.js vercel ai project
I'm trying to generate object with vercel ai sdk, here is the example:
https://sdk.vercel.ai/examples/next-app/basics/generating-object
But the problem is, I dont wanna use open ai, I'm using together ai models, and to use that in the example code, I need to create a custom provider. Anyone know how?
I've tried to create a custom provider and pass it's model but it didnt work.
https://sdk.vercel.ai/providers/community-providers/custom-providers
